# How to find total derivative of function $f$ from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

I'm trying to find the total derivative $Df(x,y)$ of $f(x,y)=y\cos x$.

I'm familiar with this definition mostly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map

I believe there is a theorem that states that if the partial derivatives exist and are continuous, then $f$ is differentiable. I haven't learned this theorem in class however, and would like to avoid using it if possible. Is there any easy ways to see if this derivative even exists on $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's unclear exactly what you're allowed to use here, but if a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is $\mathscr{C}^1$ we can write its total derivative in terms of the $m\times n$ Jacobian matrix: 
$$
\text{Jac}(f)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So, for us this is simple because our map is $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ and we just have to produce a $1\times 2$ matrix of partials. These are $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-y\sin x$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\cos x$. Then the total derivative at $(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is represented by the matrix 
$$ 
\text{Jac}(f)_{(x_0,y_0)}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-y_0\sin x_0 &\cos x_0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that the Jacobian represents the total derivative (which is a linear map), so multiplying the matrix by a vector in $\mathbb R^2$ gives its image in $\mathbb R$. Is there way to write the total derivative as an actual linear map and not its matrix representation? In my class, we seem distinguish the actual linear map from the matrix representing it.

Comment: Once you identify a basis, a matrix _is_ a linear transformation by $v\mapsto Av$.

Comment: $$Df(x_0,y_0)(h,k) = -hy_0\sin x_0+k\cos x_0.$$